# What is the best location to store Appium tests? Same Android repo? separated automation repository?

Tags: android, selenium, junit, appium, integration-testing

I am developing an automation framework using Appium and Webdriver. I have a bunch of classes for the framework and JUnit tests. Everything is working in a separated repository in which the appium server is initialized, the tests run and then the server is terminated.

My question is if I should move those tests into the Android app repo, in order for the developers to have a more confortable access to them and run the tests against a dev or debug apk.

Some questions:

1) Should these appium tests be located on the test folder (unit tests) or androidTest (instrumented tests)?

2) How is the best way to execute test tasks in gradle in order to generate an apk (with different flavors/environments), install it in a phone or emulator and run the tests?

I haven't found a lot of examples answering these questions in the web.

Thanks!